# CIR process characteristic function

Tags: stochastic-processes, characteristic-function

what is the characteristic function of the CIR process given by
$dv_t = \kappa (\theta - v_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t}dW_t$
Unfortunately, I could not find the answer in the literature.
I know it is in the class of affine diffusion processes, but how can we find the characteristic function?

Answer (score 5):

The distribution of the variance $v_t$ is known, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model#Distribution). We have $$v_t=\frac{1}{2c_t}Y,$$ where $$c_t=\frac{2\kappa}{(1-e^{-\kappa t})\sigma^2}$$ and $Y$ follows a [non-central $\chi^2$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) with $k=\frac{4\kappa\theta}{\sigma^2}$ degrees of freedom and  non-centrality parameter $\lambda_t=2c_tv_0e^{-\kappa t}$. The characteristic function of $Y$ is known to be
$$\varphi_Y(u)=\frac{1}{(1-2iu)^{k/2}}\exp\left(\frac{iu\lambda_t}{1-2iu}\right).$$
The characteristic function of $v_t$ is thus
$$\varphi_{v_t}(u)=\varphi_{Y/2c_t}(u)=\varphi_Y\left(\frac{u}{2c_t}\right)=\frac{1}{(1-iu/c_t)^{k/2}}\exp\left(\frac{iu\lambda_t/2}{c_t-iu}\right).$$

This is the characteristic function of $v_t$, i.e. the variance in the [Heston (1993)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/6/2/327/1574747) model or the short rate $r_t$ in the [Cox et al. (1985)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1911242?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) model. This is very different to the characteristic function of the (log-)stock price in the [Heston (1993)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/6/2/327/1574747) model that you need for usual option pricing.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Kevin ‘s splendid answer, you can make use of the affine properties you have just described. The relevant machinery is found in [DPS2000](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/%7Edbackus/Disasters/DuffiePanSingleton%20jumps%20Econometrica%2000.PDF), equations (2.4) thru (2.6).

We are looking for

$$ \phi(u,t) \equiv E\left(e^{iuv_t}\right)$$

where $E(\cdot)\equiv E(\cdot|\mathcal{F_0})$. For affine processes, this expectation can be solved thru a cleverly chosen set of differential equations, i.e. Feynman-Kac (see paper):

$$ \phi(u,s) = E\left(e^{\alpha_s + \beta_s v_s}\right) \mathrm{s.t.} \alpha_t=0, \beta_t=ui$$

Where the functions $\alpha(t), \beta(t)$ satisfy ordinary differential equations in case of a CIR process:

$$\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \tau} = -\kappa\beta_\tau + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\beta_\tau^2$$ subject to $\beta_0 = ui$ and
$$ \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \tau}=\kappa\theta\beta_\tau$$
subject to $\alpha_0=0$

*NB: I have flipped the time dimension from $s:0\to t$ to $\tau:t\to 0$, hence you find different signs when comparing to the paper*

You can now solve the ODEs, starting with $\beta$ and plugging the result back into the ODE for $\alpha$.